# Formulation Formatting

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to save my formulas to SQL and use it in both the controller side and javascript side on my .net core project.

`{H}+({FA}*2)+{VW}`

Formulas are like this format. I want to change values of H, FA and VW with numbers.

```
string str2 = "{H}+({FA}*2)+{VW}";
string str3 = string.Format(str2, 60, 10, 20);
string value = new DataTable().Compute(str, null).ToString();
```

I can calculate like this on the controller side. (If there is a better way for it i can get advice too.)
I need to do on JavaScript side too. What should I do?

---

EDIT;
Btw C# code doesn't work, here is the working one i need a modular thing but i don't know how to do it.

```
var H = "150";
var VW = "200";
var FA = "20";
string str = $"{H}+{VW}*2";
string value = new DataTable().Compute(str, null).ToString();
```

I can use `string.replace` but I've 26 variable and will be complex. I'm adding more examples to formulas.

```
string formula1 = {H}+({FA}*2)+{VW};
string formula2 = {W}+({FA}*2)+{HW};
string formula3 = {FA}*2+{GFH}-{MTF};
string formula4 = {VSP}/{FA}+{GFV}*(A+B+C);
string formula5 = {TH}+{W}*2+{FT}*2;
```

***EDIT2:
I'm thinking about to use this on C# side.

```
public void CalculateTest()
    {
        List<varKeyDto> varKeys = new List<varKeyDto>(){
            new varKeyDto(){
               Variable = "H",
                Value ="150"
            },
            new varKeyDto(){
               Variable = "VW",
                Value ="200"
            },
            new varKeyDto(){
               Variable = "FA",
                Value ="20"
            },
        };

        string formula = "{H}+({FA}*2)+{VW}";
        string cmptd = ReturnFormula(formula, varKeys);
    }
    public string ReturnFormula(string formula, List<varKeyDto> varKeys)
    {
        string formulaString = formula;
        foreach (var varKey in varKeys)
        {
            formulaString = formulaString.Replace("{" + varKey.Variable + "}", varKey.Value);
        }
        string value = new DataTable().Compute(formulaString, null).ToString();
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: That "controller side" code won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could process the string to extract the variable names and make it valid JavaScript code and use all that to create a `Function`, here is an example:

```js
const str = '{H}+({FA}*2)+{VW}';
const vars = str.match(/{[A-Z]+}/g).map(v => v.replace(/[{}]/g, ''));
const fnBody = str.replace(/[{}]/g, '');
const fn = new Function(...vars, `return ${fnBody}`);

const result = fn(60, 10, 20);
console.log(result);
```

The generated function looks something like this:

```
function (H, FA, VW) {
  return H+(FA*2)+VW
}
```

Comment: This answer is good. But i've got 26 variable. Formulas can be complex.

Comment: @emroo That shouldn't be a problem, this will work if all the variables look the same (`{` followed by one or multiple upper case letter and a `}` at the end).

Comment: You can do the same thing with C#, code is a bit more verbose but injecting the formula into the script is a good way to go with dynamic formulas, hundreds of parameters to the method would not be a big deal as the code is largely generating the interface for you from existing properties. Just make sure you test your formulas thoroughly and handle any exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot format string with such custom literals, they have to be like - `{0} {1} {2}` and so on.

You can use `.Replace` instead -

```
var formulaString = formula.Replace("{H}", "1").Replace("{FA}", "2").Replace("{VW}", "3");
string value = new DataTable().Compute(formulaString, null).ToString();
```

In javascript you can use `.replaceAll`-

```js
 var formula = "{H}+({FA}*2)+{VW}";
 var formulaString = formula.replaceAll("{H}", 1).replaceAll("{FA}", 2).replaceAll("{VW}", 3)
 console.log(eval(formulaString));
```

Comment: I have much more variables and it will be hard to handle all this formulas.